# Search Function Python using 2D array list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do a search function for a 2 dimension array or list. How do I search thru this list and return the values of the items.

```
myfoodlist = [("Chicken Pasta", 10),("Beef Noodle", 12),("Hot Coffee", 4.20),( "Fish and Chips", 8.50)]

foodsearch = raw_input("Please input food to search: ")

        for item in (myfoodlist) :

            if item.find(foodsearch) != -1:
                searchReturnsItems.append(item)
        for item in searchReturnsItems:
            print(item, "\t:\t")
        searchReturnsItems.clear()
```

Example

I like to ask for a key word like "beef" and return a list of all beef items and store in array.

Above is my code and I have some challenges.

Anyone can provide me an example to search a 2D array will be helpful

Comment: Will each food item pair always contain food name as it's first entry?

Comment: The first item is the food menu and then price so yes.

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly modified your searching method to use list comprehension, and use `re` package to support partial case insensitive searches.

```
import re

myfoodlist = [("Chicken Pasta", 10),("Beef Noodle", 12),("Hot Coffee", 4.20),( "Fish and Chips", 8.50)]

foodsearch = input("Please input food to search: ")

searchReturnsItems = [item for item in myfoodlist if re.search(foodsearch, item[0], re.IGNORECASE)]

for item in searchReturnsItems:
    print(item, "\t:\t")
searchReturnsItems.clear()
```

Output

```
Please input food to search: beef
('Beef Noodle', 12)
```

Comment: You might need to use regex match to allow for partial and case insensitive matches.

Comment: if my list is now changed to a python dictionary, how will it be different?

Comment: ```myfoodlist = { "Beef Noodle" : 12, "Chicken Pasta" : 10, "Hot Coffee" : 4.20, "Fish and Chips" :8.50} ```

Answer (score 0):

```
myfoodlist = [("Chicken Pasta", 10),("Beef Noodle", 12),("Hot Coffee", 4.20),( "Fish and Chips", 8.50)]

foodsearch = input("Please input food to search: ")

def searchFood():

        for item in (myfoodlist) :

            if(item[0]==foodsearch):

                return item[0],item[1]
searchFood()
```

output

Please input food to search: Hot Coffee

Out[2]:
('Hot Coffee', 4.2)